# How to create a new branch which contains source of another branch - rtc source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I have a stream which contains multiple components.
I want to break this stream into a development and a production stream (a bit like the ClearCase UCM Integration and Development Streams) .

How do I accomplish this ?
(In ClearCase, it was about creating a sub-Stream to an existing Stream)

Something like :

- Rename the current stream to dev-stream.
- Create a new stream prod-stream.
- Create new components to match components in '`dev-stream`' and add them to '`prod-stream`'

I have a workspace which flows with the stream 'dev-stream'.
To copy the code from the '`dev stream`' to the '`prod stream`', do I need to change my workspace flow target from '`dev-stream`' to '`prod-stream`' and deliver changes to this new stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RTC, you don't have to create new components.
You can rename an existing stream at any time.

Then I would advise to create a snapshot on that existing (and renamed) stream in order to take a picture of all the component.

You can create a new stream and add that snapshot in it: all the components will be added on one operation.
You don't need to copy any file.

You will create a second repo workspace on that second stream and will load it any directory you want in a second local workspace or sandbox.

Comment: Can I then automatically merge code from the dev stream to the prod stream ?

Comment: @user470184 If you set a snapshot on the first stream, the content of the second stream will be identical. But then, you will be able to merge from the first stream to the second. See https://jazz.net/library/article/40/ .

Comment: when I create the new stream from the snapshot repository all of  the new stream components are the same as previous. So 'dev-stream' & 'prod-stream' have the same components (the components have the same name and point to same baseline). Should a copy of the components not instead have been created with the new baseline ?

Comment: I've posted a new question to address above. Thanks for your answer