# Change name of component

Tags: version-control, clearcase, rtc

To create a new `dev` stream from an existing stream, I first created a snapshot of the existing stream and from this snapshot I created a new `prod` stream.
(similar to a ClearCase UCM rebase of a baseline from a parent Stream to a  child Stream)

All of the new stream components are the same as previous. So '`dev-stream`' & '`prod-stream`' have the same components (the components have the same name and point to same baseline).
Should a copy of the components not instead have been created with the new baseline ?

Here is a snapshot of how my component appears in RTC for both '`dev-stream`' & '`prod-stream`' :

[image]

The baseline should not contain the word "`prod`" as this is a `dev` stream.
The problem is circled in red in screenshot: How or why has the word '`prod`' appeared in the component name ? Can '`prod`' be removed from the name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component must be the same when you add a snapshot to a new stream : same name and same baseline name. (very similar to a ClearCase UCM rebase, where you would find the same baseline name used as a *foundation* baseline for the sub-stream).

The idea behind a stream is to list what you need in order to work : this is called a configuration, as in "scm" (which can stand for "source *configuration* management", not just "source *code* management").

The fact that your new stream starts working with a baseline named with "`prod`" in it has no bearing on the kind of development you are about to do in said new stream.
It is just a "starting point" (like "foundation baselines" in ClearCase are). Again, no copy or rename involved here.

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544233/how-to-create-a-new-branch-which-contains-source-of-another-branch-rtc-source), you mentioned having the current stream as '`dev-stream`', but that has no influence on the name of the baselines already delivered in that first Stream (whatever its name is). Those baselines keep their name, and if you snapshot them and reuse that snapshot in a new stream, you will get the exact same baseline name.

But the name of the first baseline you are using as a starting point doesn't matter, as long as its content allows you to start a separate development effort, isolated in its own stream.
Any baseline you will create and deliver on said new stream will be displayed on it, and you won't see anymore that first baseline name.

Comment: The baseline should not contain the word "prod" as this is a dev stream. Are the components in each of the streams independent of each other even though they have same name and same baseline name. ie delivering to one component in stream has no impact on another component of same name and baseline name in another stream ?

Comment: @user470184 the name of the baseline is of  no consequence; it is just a starting point. Create anew baseline in your new repo workspace on your new stream, and deliver it: you will see it displayed in said new stream. But until you create those new baselines, you pick up as a starting point the baseline you snapshotted in your previous stream in order to initialized the new one. This is similar to the ClearCase foundation baselines. The fact that you have renamed the former stream 'dev' doesn't change anything to the baselines already created on it (and reuse in the new one)

Comment: @user470184 I have edited my answer to reiterate the point I am making in my previous comment.